# Bridge Firewall vs Routing Firewall

Tags: firewalls, iptables

What is the difference between bridge and routing firewall ?

How they both works and what are the **security advantages/disadvantages for both scenario** ?

Answer (score 5):

A routing firewall participates in the IP process, whereas a bridging, or transparent, firewall does not. A transparent firewall acts more as a tap on a line, while a routing firewall has to forward traffic onto its next destination.

The advantages of a transparent firewall are that it can be installed in-line between two devices without having to reconfigure the IP subnet used as the interfaces on the firewall are unnumbered. From a security perspective a transparent firewall is quieter, as it does not participate in IP connections an attacker may not even know it is there unless something is blocked. An attacker will have difficulty determining the type of firewall being used.

The advantages of a routing firewall is that as it participates in the IP protocol it can do network address translation, port translation, and tricks like source port scrambling to make fingerprinting more difficult. A transparent firewall cannot provide these types of services.

As for which to use, it depends on the problem you are trying to solve. Routed firewalls provide the most capability and flexibility, but transparent firewalls can be inserted into connections without requiring substantial network changes.

Answer (score 0):

Bridge firewalls are simpler devices that operate at the MAC address level, making them suitable for basic network segmentation and filtering. Routing firewalls, on the other hand, offer more advanced security features by operating at the IP and port level, allowing for granular control and stateful inspection. The choice between them depends on your network's complexity and security requirements. In most cases, routing firewalls are preferred for reasonable network security due to their advanced capabilities, but bridge firewalls may still have specific use cases in simpler setups.
However it is worthy to mention that the era is now of Next Generation Firewall (Nex gen) firewall the above mentioned both firewalls are now become obsolete and irrelevant.

Comment: Specifying the OSI Layer numbers and names would be a good addition

Comment: Please do not post AI-generated content, even if you include non-AI generated content in it.